# Prisma/MySQL - Question about nested upsert (Update or Create)

Tags: javascript, mysql, reactjs, next.js, prisma

I'm trying to implement a nested upsert as in the prisma docs:

https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/relation-queries#update-or-create-a-related-record

I have a product which I want to add to basket. If the basket already contains the product, I want to update the amount to 5.

```
  if (req.method == "PUT") {
    const productId = req.body.id;

    const newBasket = await prisma.basket.update({
      where: { id: 6 },
      data: {
        basketProduct: {
          upsert: {
            create: { productId: productId, amount: 1 },
            update: { productId: productId, amount: 5 },
          },
        },
      },
    });
    return res.status(201).send(newBasket);
  }
```

If I understand correctly this is how it should work, however I'm getting the following error

```
error - PrismaClientValidationError:
Invalid `prisma.basket.update()` invocation:

{
  where: {
    id: 6
  },
  data: {
    basketProduct: {
      upsert: {
        create: {
          productId: 61,
          amount: 1
        },
        update: {
          productId: 61,
          amount: 5
        },
+       where: {
+         id?: Int,
+         productId?: Int
+       }
      }
    }
  }
}

Argument where for data.basketProduct.upsert.where is missing.
```

Apparently I need a where in my upsert, but it doesn't mention it in the docs.

These are my models

```
model Basket {
  id              Int       @id @default(autoincrement())
  basketProduct   BasketProduct[]
  @@map(name: "basket")
}

model BasketProduct {
  id              Int       @id @default(autoincrement())    
  amount          Int
  basket          Basket    @relation(fields: [basketId], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade)
  basketId        Int       @map("basket_id")
  product         Product   @relation(fields: [productId], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade)
  productId       Int       @unique @map("product_id")
  @@map(name: "basket_product")
}
```